How to set background Color and tint Color in QLPreviewController
I am showing some data by using QLPreviewController which is a part of DetailViewController and DetailViewController is part of UINavigationViewController(Mean we have navigation bar with back button and title), now I wanter to push the QLPreviewController which is again working fine as per our requirement but when QLPreviewController got pushed, back button is not showing but working fine
//PDF viewer 
let quickLookController = QLPreviewController()

func showDocPreview() {
  quickLookController.reloadData()
  if QLPreviewController.canPreview(viewModel.fileURLs[0] as QLPreviewItem {
    quickLookController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0
    navigationController?.pushViewController(quickLookController, animated: true)
  }

Note:- Above code is working fine just back button is not visible, I also try to add tint or background color but that is not woking
